# Shuffle Array with a twist

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a grid layout. I can get the tiles laid out correctly until I shuffle the xposArray.

```
 populateXPosArray:function(){
        var i = arr.length;

        for(j=0;j<i;j++){

            if((j % cols) === 0){
                ypos += 70;//height of the tile
                xpos = 0;
            }
            xposArray.push(xpos);
            xpos += 70;//width of the tile

        }

        //tryApp.shuffleArray(xposArray);

        console.log("xPosArray : " + xposArray);//returns 0,70,140,210, 280,0,70,140,210,280,0,70,140,210,280,0,70,140,210,280,0,70,140,210, 280
    },

    shuffleArray:function(array){
        //Fisher–Yates shuffle    
        var m = array.length, t, i;
        // While there remain elements to shuffle…
        while (m) {
            // Pick a remaining element…
            i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

            // And swap it with the current element.
            t = array[m];
            array[m] = array[i];
            array[i] = t;
        }

        return array;
    },
```

This works perfectly laying out the tiles in a 5 column 5 row grid. If I use the shuffleArray function then the array is returned as the below which is as expected but not what I am trying to achieve. () Brackets are only for illustration purposes and as you can see there values are duplicated in each group of 5 which I need to avoid.

```
 (280,140,140,140,210),(70,70,280,280,210),(0,140,210,0,140),(210,210,70,70,0),(70,0,0,280,280)
```

Is there a way to only shuffle the first 5 elements and then the second 5 etc etc so that none of the same values appear in the same group of 5? So an example of the output would be:

```
 (0,280,140,70,210),(70,0,210,140,280),(280,210,140,70,0),(210,70,140,280,0),(140,210,280,0,70);
```

Comment: You want to generate some of the possible **permutations** of the array elements. Search for an algorithm that generates permutations.

Answer (score 0):

you can split the array in N sections and then map the shuffle function for each sub array.

```
function split(a, n) {
    var len = a.length,out = [], i = 0;
    while (i < len) {
        var size = Math.ceil((len - i) / n--);
        out.push(a.slice(i, i + size));
        i += size;
    }
    return out;
}

var xset = split(xposArray,5);
var yset = xset.map(shuffleArray);
var flatten_arr = [];
var result = flatten_arr.concat.apply(flaten_arr, yset);
```